# List of available wifi connections using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking for an example to list all wifi connections that are availables by using Xamarin Forms.

All of examples that I found was to check if the current connection is on or off. But I'd like to list all avaliable connections and get all of information about them.

I am not sure if this plugin "Plugin.Connectivity" could help me but it was the more  close I got from my goal.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this one?

Answer (score -1):

The Connectivity (which is now part of [Xamarin.Essentials](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials)) plugin is not going to help with this, unfortunately. It only allows you to see if you have a connection and tells you something about that.

As far as I know, there is no library for this and you will have to write custom code for this. I'm not sure what platforms you are targeting, I'll assume iOS and Android.

For iOS, you probably want to look at the [NEHotspotHelper](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/NetworkExtension.NEHotspotHelper/) and list the `SupportedNetworkInterfaces` property. And do something like this:

```
foreach (var network in NEHotspotHelper.SupportedNetworkInterfaces)
    Console.WriteLine(network.Ssid);
```

Don't forget to enable the NetworkExtensions entitlement in the Entitlements.plist

For Android, the code could look something like this:

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
foreach ( WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces )
{
    // Lists all networks
    Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList( 0 );
    foreach ( Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Found network with SSID {0}.", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid));
    }
}
```

On Android, you will need an extra permission to be able to do this.

To make it suitable for Forms, wrap it into a DependencyService and move back and forth the information you need.

Comment: Hi Gerald Versluis, I am not sure if I'll be able to get a list of avaliable wifi connections with Xamarin.Essentials.  I've tried and I notice that I can check the current connection, but I can't list all avaliables connections.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to list all actual WiFi network near to me.

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood you. As far as I know, there is no library for that. This plugin cannot do it. And I'm not even sure if you can do it from iOS as Apple won't allow it

Comment: Updated with a more relevant answer

Comment: But what is this WlanClient, I mean, what is this dll?